# How can I pull every linux kernel commit request?

Tags: linux, git, kernel

I am looking for a way to pull all requests that have ever been submitted for inclusion in the linux kernel.  I want all code that was actually accepted by Linux and company, and all code that was rejected.  Is this possible?

I understand I can check out the source and see the commit log for all accepted patches....but the real question is how to get all of the patches/code that has been rejected?

The reason I ask this question is that I thought it would be cool to take all accepted and rejected patches/additions to the linux kernel, feed it into google predictions for analysis, and each time a new patch is submitted you could see the percentage of your patch actually being accepted by Linus et al. :)

Thanks in advance for the responses!

Answer (score 3):

You can't get information about rejected patches from git.  You may get experimental branches — you should also look at kernel mailing lists as that's where most patches get posted for inclusion.  GIT is not used as a submission vehicle by all contributors; the mailing lists are.

Comment: Further, some patches may come out-of-band from a maintainer. There is no collection of things rejected, only a history of how things were applied.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to retrieve all **publicly** rejected code, you'll need to:

- follow all the Linux development mailing lists;
- search for patches and pull request;
- compare them with all the sub-maintainers git trees, linux-next, and/or linus' git tree.

I guess you'll hit several issues:

- time delta between patch submission and Linux tree inclusion (can be several months);
- code review and several versions of the same patch does not mean the first patch was rejected;
- ...

That's an interesting project, but looks quite complex to me if you want to make it complete. And you'll only get the **public** code submission that was "rejected".